# Style Trigger only working one way when bound to IsEnabled of custom class

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I made a custom TimePicker and am trying to have it disabled from the start, and only enable it whenever something was done first. To make it show as disabled I use a Style trigger to change it's appearence related to it's IsEnabled property.

My problem though is that this trigger only worked in first initialization so the style looks like its disabled. but once I Enable it the trigger doesnt change the appearence back. What am I missing?

my trigger

```
<Style TargetType="customControlls:BorderedTimePicker">
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger TargetType="customControlls:BorderedTimePicker" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource varColBgGrey}" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource varColBgGrey}" />
        <Setter Property="Image" Value="ClockDisabled.png" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

To more clarify, I am sure that IsEnabled got changed since the TimePicker works after setting enabled to true, but the appearence still doesn't change.

My custom TimePicker:

public class BorderedTimePicker : TimePicker
{
    #region Bindables

```
public static readonly BindableProperty MinimumTimeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MinimumTime), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(BorderedTimePicker), null);

public DateTime MinimumTime
{
    get => (DateTime)GetValue(MinimumTimeProperty);
    set => SetValue(MinimumTimeProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty MaximumTimeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MaximumTime), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(BorderedTimePicker), null);

public DateTime MaximumTime
{
    get => (DateTime)GetValue(MaximumTimeProperty);
    set => SetValue(MaximumTimeProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(BorderedTimePicker), Color.DarkGray, BindingMode.TwoWay);

public Color BorderColor
{
    get => (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty);
    set
    {
        SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public static readonly BindableProperty TextSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TextSize), typeof(int), typeof(BorderedTimePicker), 16);

public int TextSize
{
    get => (int)GetValue(TextSizeProperty);
    set => SetValue(TextSizeProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty BorderThicknessProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderThickness), typeof(double), typeof(BorderedTimePicker), 2.0);

public double BorderThickness
{
    get => (double)GetValue(BorderThicknessProperty);
    set => SetValue(BorderThicknessProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty BorderRadiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderRadius), typeof(double), typeof(BorderedTimePicker), 20.0);

public double BorderRadius
{
    get => (double)GetValue(BorderRadiusProperty);
    set => SetValue(BorderRadiusProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceholderProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Placeholder), typeof(string), typeof(BorderedTimePicker), string.Empty);

public string Placeholder
{
    get => (string)GetValue(PlaceholderProperty);
    set => SetValue(PlaceholderProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty ImageProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Image), typeof(string), typeof(BorderedTimePicker), string.Empty, BindingMode.TwoWay);

public string Image
{
    get => (string)GetValue(ImageProperty);
    set
    {
        SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public static readonly BindableProperty ImageSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ImageSize), typeof(int), typeof(BorderedTimePicker), 35);

public int ImageSize
{
    get => (int)GetValue(ImageSizeProperty);
    set => SetValue(ImageSizeProperty, value);
}

public static readonly BindableProperty IsValidProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsValid), typeof(bool), typeof(BorderedDatePicker), true);

public bool IsValid
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsValidProperty);
    set
    {
        SetValue(IsValidProperty, value);
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public static readonly BindableProperty NullableDateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NullableDate), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), null, BindingMode.TwoWay);

public DateTime? NullableDate
{
    get => (DateTime?)GetValue(NullableDateProperty);
    set
    {
        if (value != NullableDate)
        {
            SetValue(NullableDateProperty, value);
            UpdateDate();
        }
    }
}

#endregion Bindables

public BorderedTimePicker()
{
}

private void UpdateDate()
{
    if (NullableDate.HasValue)
    {
        Time = NullableDate.Value.TimeOfDay;
    }
}

protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
{
    base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

    if (propertyName == TimeProperty.PropertyName)
    {
        if (NullableDate != null) NullableDate = NullableDate.Value + Time;
    }
}
```

EDIT: the relevant part of my viewCell where I use the trigger and the timepicker

```
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:customControlls="clr-namespace:CleanKISeCare.CustomControlls;assembly=CleanKISeCare"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.ListView.XForms.Helpers;assembly=Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms"
             xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:CleanKISeCare.Converter;assembly=CleanKISeCare"
             x:Class="CleanKISeCare.CustomControlls.DatePickerComponent" 
             x:Name="this">
             <ViewCell.BindingContext>
                  <helpers:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="InverseBoolConverter" />
              </ViewCell.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout x:Name="mainView" BindingContext="{Binding .}" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="10">
         <StackLayout.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <helpers:InverseBoolConverter x:Key="InverseBoolConverter" />
                    <converter:StringDateTimeConverter x:Key="StringDateTimeConverter" />
                    <Style TargetType="customControlls:BorderedTimePicker">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger TargetType="customControlls:BorderedTimePicker" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{StaticResource varColBgGrey}" />
                                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource varColBgGrey}" />
                                <Setter Property="Image" Value="ClockDisabled.png" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
</StackLayout.Resources>
            <Grid Margin="10"
                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <customControlls:BorderedTimePicker
                    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                    x:Name="timePicker"
                    Image="ClockPicker.png"
                    TextSize="14"
                    WidthRequest="160"
                    Placeholder="Zeit"
                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    MinimumTime="{Binding MinValue, Converter={StaticResource StringDateTimeConverter}}"
                    MaximumTime="{Binding MaxValue, Converter={StaticResource StringDateTimeConverter}}"
                    NullableDate="{Binding Answer, Source={x:Reference this}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    BorderColor="{StaticResource varColLightDark}"
                    TextColor="{StaticResource varColDark}"
                    Format="HH:mm" />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
</ViewCell>
```

and the code behind:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class DatePickerComponent : ViewCell
{
    public DatePickerComponent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timePicker.IsEnabled = datePicker.NullableDate != null;
    }

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        DatePickerComponent component = bindable as DatePickerComponent;
        component?.SetDate(newvalue);
    }

    void SetDate(object newvalue)
    {
        timePicker.IsEnabled = newDate.Value.Date != defaultDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code from the page where you are using the TimePicker in your XAML

Comment: @DenseCrab I added some more code